# BCE Dates in Swift

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I can't seem to figure out how to represent BCE dates (**B**efore **C**ommon **E**ra / negative years), the conversion seems to always mess up the year. Here's some playground code to show the issue :

```swift
import Foundation

var date = DateComponents()
date.year = -100
date.month = 1
date.day = 1
date.description
let realDate = Calendar.current.date(from: date)
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: realDate!)
components.year // Returns 101 !?
```

How should I go about creating a valid BCE date ? Preferably from `DateComponents`, but other answers accepted as well !

Comment: DateComponents has a property `era` that you can set, for a Gregorian calendar you should set it to 0 for BC/BCE ( and 1 for AD/CE)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Do years with era 0 properly work backwards ?

Comment: It will work properly with BCE, but you need to provide years as positive numbers, not negative

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
extension Date {
    
    static public func from(year : Int? = nil, month : Int? = nil, day : Int? = nil) -> Date? {
        
        //Year 0 is invalid
        if nil != year && year! == 0 {
            return nil
        }
        
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        
        dateComponents.month = month
        dateComponents.day = day

        if nil != year {
            //era for BCE = 0, otherwise 1
            dateComponents.era = (year! < 0) ? 0 : 1
            dateComponents.year = (dateComponents.era == 1) ? year : year! * -1
        }

        
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)
        return date
    }
    
    public func dateParts() -> (year : Int?, month : Int?, day : Int?) {
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .era], from: self)
        
        var year = components.year
        if components.era == 0 {    //BCE
            if nil != year {
                year = year! * -1
            }
        }

        return (year, components.month, components.day)
    }
}
```